# Blazor (Server-side) Global Exception Handler

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to create C# Blazor (Server-side) Global Exception Handler?
(not webassembly)

I am looking for a global exception handler like ASP.NET with logging of exception into text file.

I checked here & no answer on blazor (server-side)
(not webassembly)

Answer (score 2):

```
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase
    <div class="page">
       <div class="sidebar">
          <NavMenu />
       </div>
       <main>
          <div class="top-row px-4">
             <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
          </div>
          <article class="content px-4">
             <ErrorBoundary>
                <ChildContent>
                   @Body
                </ChildContent>
                <ErrorContent>
                   <p>&#128165; Something blew up!</p>
                 @{
                   Logging Actions
                  }
                </ErrorContent>
             </ErrorBoundary>
          </article>
       </main>
    </div>
```

Use the **ErrorBoundary Component**
Wrap the `@Body` directive inside the `ErrorBoundary` component. This will catch any unhandled exceptions that occur in any of the child components rendered within the `@Body`.

Answer (score -3):

To create a global exception handler for a server-side Blazor application, you can implement a middleware for handling exceptions and logging them to a text file. This approach is similar to handling exceptions in ASP.NET Core applications. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. **Create a Middleware for Exception Handling:**
   Define a new middleware class that will catch and log exceptions.

   ```cs
   public class ErrorLoggingMiddleware
   {
       private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
       private readonly ILogger<ErrorLoggingMiddleware> _logger;

       public ErrorLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorLoggingMiddleware> logger)
       {
           _next = next;
           _logger = logger;
       }

       public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
       {
           try
           {
               await _next(context);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception.");
               throw; // Re-throwing the exception is important to not break the middleware pipeline
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Register the Middleware:**
   In your `Startup.cs`, register the middleware in the `Configure` method.

   ```cs
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
       // ... other configurations ...

       app.UseMiddleware<ErrorLoggingMiddleware>();

       // ... other configurations ...
   }
   ```
3. **Configure Logging to a Text File:**
   To log exceptions to a text file, you can use a logging provider like NLog or Serilog that supports file logging. Here's an example of setting up NLog:

   - First, add the NLog package to your project via NuGet.
   - Then, configure NLog in `nlog.config` file in your project root:

     ```xml
     <nlog>
       <targets>
         <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/logfile.txt" />
       </targets>
       <rules>
         <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" />
       </rules>
     </nlog>
     ```
   - In `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`, configure NLog:

     ```cs
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
         try
         {
             // Application startup logic
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Catch setup-related exceptions
             logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of an exception.");
             throw;
         }
         finally
         {
             // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit
             NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
         }
     }
     ```

This setup will allow your server-side Blazor application to catch and log exceptions globally, writing them to a specified text file. Adjust the logging level and output format as needed for your specific requirements.

Comment: Middleware only applies to HTTP. Blazor runs on SignalR.